# one-or-more pattern in parameter substitution in bash

Tags: bash

I wonder whether there is a way to specify an one-or-more modifier for a character class in a parameter substitution pattern in bash, similar to a regex: i.e. `[a-z]+`. It seems like that for instance to remove all trailing whitespaces from a variable I would need to use `${fn##*[[:space:]]}` (would only work for `fn="  test"` but not for `fn="  test a"`) however I was hoping for something like `${fn##[[:space:]]+}`. Is there a special syntax to specify regex instead of the patterns? Where is the pattern format specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `extglob`, you can do this:

```
shopt -s extglob
fn="  test a"
echo "${fn##+([[:space:]])}"
```

```
test a
```

Here glob expression `+([[:space:]])` matches 1 or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use regular expressions in parameter expansions like that. However, the extended pattern syntax enabled by `extglob` is equivalent in power.

```
$ fn="  test a"
$ echo "$fn"
  test a
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${fn##*([[:space:]])}"
test a
```